# Why the left DIV not covering 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="padding-top: 30px; text-align: center; position: relative;">
                    <div id="dvQuotes" style="min-height: 100px; border: 1px solid blue;">
                        <div id="dvOrangeLeftQuote" style="float: left; width: 18%; height: 100%; padding-right: 2%; background: #DDD; text-align: right;">
                            <img src="theImages/quoteOrangeLeft.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="dvOrangeQuote" style="text-align: left; width: 80%; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; font-size: medium; margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: 40px; background: #6c6c6c;">
                            I have been blessed to be assisted by this group. Everyone in all positiong have treated my like family. My doctors are more than excellent, and I can't stop telling everyone about them.
                        </div>
                        <div id="dvOrangeRightQuote" style="padding-left: 2%; float: right; width: 18%; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: #7e75f2; text-align: left;">
                            <img src="theImages/quoteOrangeRight.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

which displays:

[image]

This is what I am looking to do:

[image]

How can I achieve it?

UPDATE: when the blue border is removed, the alignment is messed up:

[image]

Comment: Side note, try to avoid inline styling.

Comment: @j08691 This was an example, everything is in a stylesheet :)

Comment: Have you tried using the same fixed height for all divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `width:60%;` and `margin:40px auto 0 auto;` to that `#dvOrangeQuote`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/zfSc2/

Comment: Sorry,  here is the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/asE2P/ If I keep the border the images are displayed correctly, as soon as I remove it, they don't align correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a `height` for the parent element.

Right now you only set the `min-height` attribute. This is handled differently than the `height` attribute and therefore the child element won't know what 100 % height is supposed to mean.

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4QM3h/).

Comment: Sorry,  here is the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/asE2P/ If I keep the border the images are displayed correctly, as soon as I remove it, they don't align correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The div containing the image will take 100% height of the image inside it. Try to change the 100% height from the 'quote-divs' to 100px as well.

Comment: When I remove the blue border the alignment are messed up. Updated my question.

Comment: you have only removed the border?

Comment: I actually put the position on the wrong DIV. Fixed now. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry,  here is the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/asE2P/ If I keep the border the images are displayed correctly, as soon as I remove it, they don't align correctly.

Comment: Add display:inline-block to the styling of "dvQuotes"

Answer (score 1):

It's ok?

http://jsfiddle.net/55ZGm/

```
<div style="padding-top: 30px; text-align: center; position: relative;">
    <div id="dvQuotes" style="min-height: 100px; border: 1px solid blue;">
        <div id="dvOrangeLeftQuote" style="float: left; width: 18%; height: 100%; padding-right: 2%; background: #DDD; text-align: right;">
            <img src="theImages/quoteOrangeLeft.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="dvOrangeQuote" style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; font-size: medium; margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: 40px;margin: 40px 22%; background: #6c6c6c;">
            I have been blessed to be assisted by this group. Everyone in all positiong have treated my like family. My doctors are more than excellent, and I can't stop telling everyone about them.
        </div>
        <div id="dvOrangeRightQuote" style="padding-left: 2%; float: right; width: 18%; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: #d00; text-align: left;">
            <img src="theImages/quoteOrangeRight.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I remove the blue border the alignment are messed up. Updated my question.

Comment: You can add overflow:hidden to #dvQuotes